Essence of thoughts in hinduism vs motivational self help book
So, as I infer from sadhguru videos thoughts and emotion have no meaning and people should be conscious about those.
In self help books for eg - Think and grow rich, there are several examples whee people got success because of their thoughts. So start thinking positively which help in success.
So, I am confused between both the philosophy.
